# Pass in range operator columnName as paramater to a custom function in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to run a custom function over a list of items which are stored in an array and I'm looking at the range operator in KQL.

Here is my code : `

```
let myfunction = (lot:string){T|where id=lot}; 
                   union( range x from 1 to 50 step 1
                         |invoke myfunction(strcat("test-",x))
                   )
```

`
but I'm getting failed message that cant resolve scalar named 'x'. What I would like to do is repeat myfunction for 50 times and then use union to merge the results of each iteration. If this can't be done by using range operator, is there an alternative way to achieve the results that I'm looking for?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The way you chose will not work because the input to the "invoke" operator is a tabular source and the function returns a tabular output.

One way to achieve this in Kusto is by using the [python plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pythonplugin).